# PopupWindow outline path

Tags: android, drawable, popupwindow

I messed up something and finally came out with nothing. 
Can somebody please show me a very basic example how to show popupwindow with border outline using Path. Please don't post XML shapes. I need to use Path because outline will not be rectangular.

I had some poc working but then I totally messed up something and don't have anything now.

Basicly what I have is (not complete code):

```
public myPop extends PopupWindow {
  public myPop(Conext context) {
    super(context);

    setFocusable(true);
    setWindowLayoutMode(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(300, View.MeasureSpec.AT_MOST), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings2, null);

    //setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));

    Path path = new Path();
    path.moveTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(100, 0);
    path.lineTo(100, 100);

    setBackgroundDrawable(new OutlineDrawable(path);

    setContentView(layout);
}

public void show() {
    showAtLocation(this.parent, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 100, 500);
}
}
```

OutlineDrawable is nothing more but just extends Drawable where in draw() I call drawPath() with given path and some paint with stroke style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry. I found my problem. Drawable Paint had alpha 0 - by mistake. I knew it must me some silly typo. Argh.